# Google Charts ColumnChart won't render because "Container is not defined"

Tags: google-api, google-visualization

The JavaScript console on Chrome says that **container is not defined** even though my `div`'s id and the id specified in `getElementById` match. Anybody know why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['corechart']});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var data = [['Year', 'Disney', 'SeaWorld', 'Universal'], ['2013', 95, 100, 102]];

    var options = 
    {
        title:"Theme Park Prices",
        width:600, 
        height:400,
        hAxis: {title: "Year"},
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('priceChart'));

    function drawChart()
    {
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }

    drawChart();

</script>

<!-- End of chart code -->

</head>

<body>

  <div id="priceChart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;margin: 0 auto;"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your JS code inside some document onload event callback, otherwise it is executed before your `div` exists and thus fails :

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){

//your JS code here

});
```

Comment: Thanks. I did that, but now I'm getting this message when I open the page: Object [object Array] has no method 'getColumnType' (you can probably tell I'm new to this whole JavaScript thing)

Comment: @Andrew Gibson : well that's another step for you to go. But if i solved your 1st problem, that would be nice to accept as answer.