# Google Chart - Container is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, google-visualization

I know this question has already been asked, but I couldn't find a lot of useful answers.
Before drawing my chart, I create the div that will hold it :

```
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
newDiv.id = ...
newDiv.class = ...
...
```

I then push it in an array that will be displayed with AngularJS via ng-repeat :

```
$scope.arrayDiv.push(newDiv);
```

Then i create the ChartWrapper :

```
var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    'chartType': chartType, 
    'containerId': $scope.arrayDiv[i].id, 
    ....
});
```

I create the DataTable (and fill it, but that's not part of the issue).

```
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
```

And finally, i draw it (or at least try) :

```
chart.setDataTable(data);
chart.draw();
```

As you guessed it, this is where i get the error `Container is not defined`.

I tried to do this to check : `console.log($scope.arrayDiv[i].id)`, and I get the expected ID.

From what I understood from other questions ([Google Charts ColumnChart won't render because "Container is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17385015/google-charts-columnchart-wont-render-because-container-is-not-defined) e.g.) the issue come from the order of the code execution. However, I want to prepare and draw my chart only when the user click on a button. How do I organize my code to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because `newDiv` isn't being added to the DOM anywhere. You would need to do something like this:

```
var currentDiv = document.getElementById("div1"); 
document.body.insertBefore(newDiv, currentDiv);
```

Comment: It worked, but don't that negate the goal of ng-repeat ? (not sure, i'm really not familiar with angular)

Also i have a new issue : the chart aren't reacting when i mouse over them.

Comment: If you're building DOM elements on your own, you are responsible for adding them to the DOM. Now, as for the events not working, I'd recommend adding another question specifically surrounding the events and detail it as well as you did this one. You wrote a great question!